# How to get fresh air to flat without letting noise in

Tags: vent, ventilation, noise-reduction, air-quality, venting

My flat is at 4th floor just next to very noisy street (cars/trams); above my flat there's only roof (no other floors or attic). I have problems with fresh air inside because I try to keep my windows as closed as I can - not to let the noise in.

How can I let fresh air to come in not letting noise to come in?

Comment: This seems like something of a project. There may be some restrictions on what you can do since you are in an apartment. Do you have rights/ability to add any kind of ventilation system, perhaps through the attic? My mind immediately conjures up something akin to a bathroom exhaust fan, but running in reverse.

Comment: Yes, I have right - or I'll get it if needed - to do some modifications to the building. Exhaust fan is noisy by itself.

Comment: Only cheap exhaust fans are noisy. You can buy high quality fans that are virtually silent.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it may be good to at least consult an HVAC specialist regarding any code implications to vents and air return modification.

From a logistics standpoint, there are several manufacturers of 'silent' centripetal inline  fans made to mate to 4" round ducting on either side.

Pair this fan with a electronically controlled damper and some exterior access with a baffle/squirrel cage and some 4" round ducting and you should be able to force fresh air into a room, or series of rooms. One might be careful to allow access to fresh air, but without allowing in all of the other elements; Hence my suggestion for an electric controlled baffle that would prevent extremely cold or hot air from passively infiltrating when the system was not on.

Since you aren't necessarily concerned with heating or cooling the room, total CFM requirements may be a lower priority than distance/degrees of separation from inside to outside. If the inline fan was remotely located near the source of the fresh air, and the run was long enough, I would be confident that you could source the air, without all the noise pollution.

TL:DR

Exterior Weather Resistance Inlet -> Electric controlled damper -> Inline Fan -> necessary Ducting -> Interior Vent